# Assign a value to a variable within a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I need to loop over files and then create for each file an object:

Here is an example :

```
filenames <- Sys.glob("/Users/Desktop/*.nwk")
for (i in filenames ) {
  print(paste0("Processing the phylogeny: ",i))
    p <- a code that generate a figure 
}
```

And then I generate 5 figures that I call with this code :

```
multiplot(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5 ncol=2, labels=c('A', 'B','C','D','E'))
```

But I wondered how can I call assign the 1,2 etc values into the variable objects p?

I tried to create a `nb=1` object and then assign as  `p+nb <- a code that generate a figure`, but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are dedicated packages for plotting/merging multiple plots. patchwork, cowplot, grid, egg, etc.

Use *lapply* to generate *ggplot* objects in a *list*, then use *cowplot::plot_grid*, something like:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(
  plotlist = lapply(list.files(...), function(i){
    #import file
    d <- read.table(i)
    #plot
    ggplot(d, aes(...)) + geom_...
  }),
  ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but I'll suggest not to create 5 plot objects in global environment. Store the output of plots in a list.

```
list_plot <- vector('list', length(filenames))

for (i in seq_along(filenames)) {
  cat("\nProcessing the phylogeny: ",filenames[i])
  list_plot[[i]] <- a code that generate a figure using filenames[i] to read file
}

do.call(multiplot, c(list_plot, ncol=2, labels=c('A', 'B','C','D','E')))
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a way by doing :

```
Phylo_name<-paste0("p",nb,sep="")
  eval(call("<-", as.name(Phylo_name), ggtree(tr = phylo,
                                              mapping = aes(color = group)) + geom_tiplab() + theme(legend.position="right")+ 
              scale_color_manual(values=color_vector)))
```

Comment: You are much better off using `assign()` rather than this `eval(call("<-"), ....)` setup. But even better don't create a bunch of loose variables in your global namespace. You can easily stick all these values in a list with `lapply` or `purrr::map`. I'm not sure which `multiplot()` function you are using but it probably has a parameter that takes a list of plots.